# Should the "code" parameter be filtered out of the logs in the oauth2 flow?

Tags: logging, oauth-2.0

I'am implementing a login flow based on oauth2.

When the user grants the permission on the oauth2 provider side, the server gets a callback with a code that can be used to retrieve the access token.

The code is by definition very short lived, but I still wonder if it is considered sensitive data that should not end in the application logs (like the password param that is sent when a user logs in via a regular form)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One time codes sent in URLs are considered safe to log. Usually they are short lived also. Other examples include `nonce` values sent in 'magic' email links. Once used they are removed from backend data and cannot be replayed. If not used they expire soon anyway.

The authorization code typically has a lifetime of a minute or two, determined by state stored in the authorization server. In any up to date code flow, redeeming a code for tokens also requires a client secret, a PKCE code verifier or both. The authorization code alone thus cannot be used to get access tokens.

Also. it is possible to send the `response_mode=form_post` parameter in the authorization request, if you prefer to receive the code in a POST response. This may have slightly worse usability though, if the user clicks the back button after login, resulting in a form resubmission warning.